# Communicate to the UI thread when a thread completes

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple program here below that has 2 threads performing some task.

Thread1 is the data feeder. Thread2 is the data processor.

So far the work being done through my approach is working but I want to have better way of getting notified when the work completes

Here is the code

```
class Program 
{
    private static BlockingCollection<int> _samples = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static bool _cancel;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart thread1 = delegate
        {
            ProcessThread1();
        };
        new Thread(thread1).Start();

        ThreadStart thread2 = delegate
        {
            ProcessThread2();
        };
        new Thread(thread2).Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel..");

        Console.Read();

        _cancel = true;
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        Console.Read();

    }

    private static void ProcessThread1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (_cancel)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Adding data..");

            _samples.TryAdd(i,100);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        // I dont like this. Instead can I get notified in the UI thread that this thread is complete.
        _cancel = true;
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    }

    private static void ProcessThread2()
    {
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int data;

            if (_samples.TryTake(out data, 100)) 
            {
                // Do some work.    
                Console.WriteLine("Processing data..");
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled.");
    }


}
```

I want the program to exit if the cancel is requested by the user or when the work completes.

I am not sure how I can get notified when the ProcessThread1 runs out of work. Currently I am setting cancel = true when the work is complete but it seem not right. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Task` instead of manually creating threads, you can attach a *continuation* on your task to notify your UI that the work is complete.

```
Task workOne = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ProcessThread1());

workOne.ContinueWith(t =>
{
     // Update UI here
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

With .NET 4.5, this becomes even easier, as you can potentially use the new `async` language support:

```
var workOne = Task.Run(ProcessThread1);
var workTwo = Task.Run(ProcessThread2);

// asynchronously wait for both tasks to complete...
await Task.WhenAll(workOne, workTwo);

// Update UI here.
```

Note that these both are designed with a user interface in mind - and will behave unusually in a console application, as there is no current synchronization context in a console application.  When you move this to a true user interface, it will behave correctly.

Comment: I went with .NET async and optimized them as mentioned by Jim. Even though the sample I gave here for console, I had to do this in WPF app which I am working to move it. Thanks for quick answers to you and Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Start one more thread whose only job is to wait on console input:

```
private void ConsoleInputProc()
{
    Console.Write("Press Enter to cancel:");
    Console.ReadLine();
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Your main thread then starts the two processing threads and the input thread.

```
// create and start the processing threads
Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(thread2);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();

// create and start the input thread
Thread inputThread = new Thread(ConsoleInputProc);
inputThread.Start();
```

Then, you wait on the two processing threads:

```
t1.Join();
// first thread finished. Request cancellation.
_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
t2.Join();
```

So if the user presses Enter, then the input thread sets the cancellation flags. thread1 and thread2 both see the cancellation request and exit.

If thread1 completes its work, then the main thread sets the cancellation flag and thread2 will cancel.

In either case, the program won't exit until thread 2 exits.

There's no need to kill the input thread explicitly. It will die when the program exits.

By the way, I would remove these lines from the thread 1 proc:

```
    // I dont like this. Instead can I get notified in the UI thread that this thread is complete.
    _cancel = true;
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

I would remove the `_cancel` variable altogether, and have the first thread check `IsCancellationRequested` just like the second thread does.

It's unfortunate that you have to start a dedicated thread to wait on console input, but it's the only way I know of to accomplish this. The Windows console doesn't appear to have a waitable event.

Note that you could do this same thing with `Task`, which overall is easier to use. The code that the tasks perform would be the same.

### Update

Looking at the bigger picture, I see that you have a typical producer/consumer setup with `BlockingCollection`. You can make your producer and consumer threads a lot cleaner:

```
private static void ProcessThread1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding data..");
        _samples.TryAdd(i, Timeout.Infinite, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        // not sure why the sleep is here
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    // Marks the queue as complete for adding.
    // When the queue goes empty, the consumer will know that
    // no more data is forthcoming.
    _samples.CompleteAdding();
}

private static void ProcessThread2()
{
    int data;
    while (_samples.TryTake(out data, TimeSpan.Infinite, _cancellationTokenSource.Token))
    {
        // Do some work.    
        Console.WriteLine("Processing data..");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled.");
}
```

You'll still need that input thread (unless you want to spin a loop on `Console.KeyAvailable`), but this greatly simplifies your producer and consumer.